# foreach usando css3

Tags: css, css3

Então, tenho uma `div` com 3 `imagens`

```
<div class="pai">
  <img src="1.jpg" />
  <img src="2.jpg" />
  <img src="3.jpg" />
</div>
```

Gostaria que essas 3 imagens corressem da direita para a esquerda em ordem até chegar em suas posições, e quando chegassem, parassem lá.

Mas gostaria que elas não saíssem todas juntas. Gostaria que a segunda desse um tempo de uns 2 segundos após a saída da primeira.

Pensando nisso, cheguei a ideia de usar um `foreach`. Mas dá para implementar isso em `css3`? como?

O modelo que fiz, apenas faz elas entrarem em sequência.

Obs: ***NÃO*** gostaria de usar JavaScript. Quero usar apenas CSS.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Documento sem título</title>
<style>
.pai {  
    width: 1000px;
    height:300px;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.pai > img {
    width: 10%;
    position:relative;
    animation: animacao 5s;
    animation-delay: 3s;
    animation-direction: alternate;
}


@keyframes animacao{
    0%   {left: 110%; top: 0px;}
    100% {left: 0px; top: 0px;}
}

</style>
</head>
<body>

  <div class="pai"> 
    <img src="1.jpg">
    <img src="2.jpg">
    <img src="3.jpg">
  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Este código não usa JS, no entanto você precisa criar o DELAY para cada item, com SASS seria possível fazer para N itens facilmente. Acrescentei o Javascript para fazer os elementos aparecerem apenas quando rola a página.

```js
$( window ).scroll(function() {
  if($( window ).scrollTop() > $('#pai').offset().top - 300)             $('#pai').addClass("pai");
 });
```

```css
#rolagem {
  width: 100%;
  height: 800px;
  background: #CCC;
}

#pai {
  width: 1000px;
  height:300px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

img {
  display: none;
}

.pai > img {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 10%;
  position:relative;
  animation: animacao 3s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

.pai > img:nth-child(2) {
  animation-delay: 2s;
  left: 110%;
}

.pai > img:nth-child(3) {
  animation-delay: 4s;
  left: 110%;
}

@keyframes animacao{
    0%   {left: 110%; top: 0px; opacity: 0;}
    55%  {opacity: 0;}
    100% {left: 0px; top: 0px; opacity: 1}
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="rolagem"></div>

<div id="pai"> 
    <img src="http://www.suasletras.com/fotos_artista/637eacb259910a2df5bde545f367ab77.jpg">
    <img src="http://www.suasletras.com/fotos_artista/637eacb259910a2df5bde545f367ab77.jpg">
    <img src="http://www.suasletras.com/fotos_artista/637eacb259910a2df5bde545f367ab77.jpg">
  </div>
```

Comment: Então, era isso mesmo. Mas aproveitando, como faz para essas figuras, em seus tempos de aparição, aparecerem como se fosse um relâmpago (clarão). Mas só aparecerem quando, ao descer a página, chegar na div delas?

Comment: Acredito que agora seja necessário JS, tu vai usar?

Comment: Não, Só queria usar CSS. É muiiiiiiiito mais rápido css e mais leve.

Comment: Acredito que para capturar a localização do Scroll seja necessário usar JS, por que não podes usar? (me explica melhor essa ideia de clarão)

Comment: kkk, ele aparece na direita com uma claridade, quando chega no meio, ele dá um clarão na imagem e depois a imagem volta ao estado de claridade normal

Comment: Acrescentei uma ideia de clarão, peço perdão por usar minha foto, era a primeira coisa que tinha a mão haha

Comment: Achei um exemplo do tipo de clarão que eu queria: https://www.nubank.com.br/gerando-boletos/, noite que ao descer (e só depois que chega na div), observe como a primeira imagem ao rolar a tela aparece. Era esse efeito de clarão que eu queria. Acho que tem a ver com a claridade da própria imagem!

Comment: hã! tua foto? Qual dos 4? O os 4? kkk

Comment: Eu mudei a foto e coloquei uma genérica do Google haha, entendi tua necessidade e já atualizo o CSS! Volto a dizer que para fazer o efeito rodar somente com o rolar da Página é preciso de Javascript.

Comment: Sim, entendi, fiz em JS puro. Mas aí me deu outra dúvida, nesse if, deverei colocar todos os elementos que estão abaixo da altura do ecrã pois a página tem várias divs uma abaixo da outra, e as divs que estão dentro da altura do ecrã? Como vou prever isso para os vários tamanhos de tela?

Comment: @CarlosRocha na verdade não `$('#pai').offset().top` pega o quanto scroll é necessário para chegar à div `#pai` independente do tamanho do ecra.

Comment: Ou seja, o top do css, ou seja, a media do inicio do browser até à  borda da div pai